# Accessing additional columns on polymorphic relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

I’m using Lumen with eloquent for this if it matters.

Howdy, I’m new to polymorphic relationships - so I’m hoping I missed something obvious here.  The relationship appears to be working correctly, however I need to return some extra data and I can’t figure out how to do it. One thing worth mentioning, my user ID is a string on purpose :).

I have Users, Ideas, and Comments.

In my Ideas model I am adding comments like this:

```
 protected $with = [
    'user:id,fname,lname',
    'comments'
];
```

This returns the following:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Mike Idea222",
    "body": "asasdasd",
    "status": "submitted",
    "user_id": "1a",
    "total_votes": 0,
    "created_at": "2021-02-16T03:36:19.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-02-16T03:36:19.000000Z",
    "user": {
        "id": "1a",
        "fname": "Michael",
        "lname": "Poopy"
    },
    "comments": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "commentable_id": 1,
            "commentable_type": "App\\Idea",
            "user_id": "1a",
            "comment": "idea It is a comment",
            "created_at": "2021-02-16T03:36:32.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-02-16T03:36:32.000000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

**WHAT I WANT** is to also have the user fname / lname show up with comment in addition to the user_id.

Perhaps I missed something - please see my code below:

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable;

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $keyType    = 'string';
    public $incrementing  = false;

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'id';
    }

    protected $with = ['ideas'];

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'fname', 'lname', 'role'];

    public function ideas()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Idea', 'id', 'user_id')
            ->select('user_id', 'id', 'title')
            ->without(['user'])
            ->without(['votes']);
    }
}
```

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('id')->unique()->primary(); // Unique UDC from CAS / banner
    $table->string('fname');
    $table->string('lname');
    $table->json('role'); // User Role
    $table->timestamps(0); // Adds nullable created_at and updated_at
});
```

**Idea.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

class Idea extends Model
{
    use Commentable;

    protected $with = [
        'user:id,fname,lname',
        'comments'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'title',
        'body',
        'status',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id')
            ->without('ideas');
    }
}
```

```
Schema::create('ideas', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->text('title');
    $table->longText('body');
    $table->text('status');
    $table->string('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->integer('total_votes')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Comment.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'comment',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'deleted_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];

    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

**Commentable.php***

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Auth;

trait Commentable
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }

    public function comment($user_id, $commentText)
    {
        $comment = new Comment();
        $comment->user_id = $user_id;
        $comment->comment = $commentText;

        $this->comments()->save($comment);
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigincrements('id');
    $table->biginteger('commentable_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->string('commentable_type');
    $table->string('user_id')->index();
    $table->longtext('comment');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by adding this to Comment.php

```
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id')
            ->select(['id', 'fname', 'lname'])
            ->without('ideas')
    }
```

And changing the morph in Commentable.php

```
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable')->with('user');
    }
```